# auto increment id by another repetition field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two column in my MySQL database.
i need to id auto increment by follow another field

example:

```
| id | orgId | createdAt |
--------------------------
| 1  | 1     | {VALUE}   |
| 2  | 1     | {VALUE}   |
| 3  | 1     | {VALUE}   |
--------------------------
| 1  | 2     | {VALUE}   |
| 2  | 2     | {VALUE}   |
--------------------------
| 1  | 3     | {VALUE}   |
| 2  | 3     | {VALUE}   |
| 3  | 3     | {VALUE}   |
| 4  | 3     | {VALUE}   |
| 5  | 3     | {VALUE}   |
--------------------------
```

I need something like that.
id must auto increment by follow (orgId) field

Comment: Don't mess with auto-increment. You could generate another ID that is not primary key with a trigger. But it would be better to generate the column on-the-fly in your select query.

Comment: Not possible using vanilla MySQL. And a dangerous thing to try and manage from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by orgId order by orgId) as id,
       t.*
from t;
```

For your purposes, I would not recommend storing this value.  Instead:

- Add an auto-incrementing id to the table.
- Use a variation on the above query to calculate the sequence number that you want:

  ```
    select row_number() over (partition by orgId order by <id col) as id,
  ```